# How to avoid multiple SQL calls in ActiveModel Serializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, active-model-serializers

I find that when I use ActiveModel Serializers to generate JSON for a set of models that include associations, it is resulting in a ton of SQL queries (one for each association). How can I avoid this?

I've tried to do an include in the controller:

```
render json: Project.includes(tasks: [:workers])
```

But this does not seem to work. Even if I pass the relation (with includes) directly to ArraySerializer it doesn't help.

Comment: If you could post your entire respond_to block, and the resulting content of your log, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit radical but for complex queries which were being hit a lot I moved the whole JSON generation into the database query (I'm using Postgres 9.3 which supports that). It probably isn't the cleanest solution as it needs pretty raw SQL but it is fast.

I'll update with an example if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 1):

I found using includes in the controller worked for me but you have to be careful that your serializer object doesn't include relationships that aren't in the includes.

Also I found if you specify a one-to-one relationship like

```
has_one :country, embed: :ids, include: false
```

it will fetch the other object even though it doesn't need to. Instead I replaced it with:

```
attributes :country_id
```

*I'm using Active Model Serializer v0.8.3*

Answer (score 0):

according the documentation[1], you are doing the things right. The Serializer just care about serialize the object. So you will need to eager load every thing you need before call the serializer.

1 - https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#performance

Answer (score 0):

Try instantiating a serializer yourself:

```
@projects = Project.includes(tasks: [:workers])
render json: ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(@projects, each_serializer: ProjectSerializer).to_json
```

Answer (score -1):

I switched to rabl. more granular and better controll